# Docker AWS Certificate Manager SSL NodsJS failure

Tags: node.js, ssl, docker, aws-cloudformation, docker-swarm

I have created and deployed a docker swarm cluster NodeJS application using the Cloudformation template provided by Docker.

My NodeJS application has both ports 80 and 443 mapped to port 3000.

I can confirm that the elastic load balancer has listeners for both ports 80 and 443.

Why is it that I can successfully reach my application on http but not on https?

for example:
http://app.myapp.com/api/health responds successfully but not https://app.myapp.com/api/health

Comment: Can you include more details? How does it not respond? How did you configure your listeners? What are the actual URLs?

Comment: I am deploying the application using docker stack. In the compose file, under the node service I am exposing 2 ports:
- "80:3000"
- "443:3000"
this automatically adds TCP listeners in the load balancer for both port 80 and port 443.

In a browser, when i visit the http page, I can see that i get results while for https the site cannot be reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging more through the web and the official docker documentations and forums.

I found the following to be really helpful https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/load-balancer/#more-full-examples

The trick was to add a label to the service and expose port 443.

Note that if you are using `stack deploy` the `label` **`should be on the deploy level not on the service level`**

here's a sample docker compose file used with stack deploy

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  node:
    image: "8574365892346589.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/app:1.5.1"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    environment:
      - APP_PORT=3000
      - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - localstorage:/home/node/app
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
      - "443:3000"
    deploy:
      mode: global
      labels:
        - "com.docker.aws.lb.arn=arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:873456923456:certificate/blahblahblahblahblahblah"
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 5s
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 5
        window: 120s

volumes:
  localstorage:
```

notice how the label is under the deploy

Hope that helps